# Can I play 2D Steam games on Windows Mixed Reality?

Tags: steam, steam-vr, windows-mixed-reality

I am considering purchasing one of the new Windows Mixed Reality headsets.

Would I be able to play games from my existing Steam library with the WMR headset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can play any steam game in the WMR headset. According to my roommate who has a Samsung headset, the experience is just like playing a 2D game on a giant screen.